# Elementary embeddings, elementary substructures,category of sets

Tags: functions, category-theory

I would like to characterize elementary embeddings AND elementary substructures in the category of sets and functions, Set. Not only characterize, but also justify this characterization.

Comment: The elementary embeddings are all bijections between finite sets and all injections between infinite sets.

Comment: What about elementary substructures in Set?

Comment: You can easily work that out yourself once you know what the elementary embeddings are.

Comment: Are you sure you are interested in $\bf{Set}$? Why not in $\bf{Mod}_\tau$ for some first order signature $\tau$?

Answer (score 0):

Since a set is a structure in the *empty* language - there's no additional structure besides the underlying carrier set itself - things are quite simple to describe.

Specifically, we have full quantifier elimination, and the quantifier-free formulas can basically only say finitely many facts about size. This analysis - which I've left a bit vague, since it's a good exercise - shows the following:

- If $A,B$ are infinite sets, then the elementary embeddings from $A$ to $B$ are precisely the injections.
- If $A,B$ are finite sets, then the elementary embeddings from $A$ to $B$ are precisely the bijections.

Since an elementary substructure is just a substructure for which the inclusion map is an elementary embedding, this also characterizes the elementary substructures: $A$ is an elementary substructure of $B$ iff $A\subseteq B$ and either $A=B$ or $A$ (and hence $B$ as well) is infinite.

Finally, note that we also get a characterization of elementary *equivalence*: $A\equiv B$ iff $A,B$ either have the same cardinality or are each infinite. In particular, two sets are elementarily equivalent iff there is an elementary embedding of one of them into the other *(since cardinalities are comparable - note that this uses a weak form of the axiom of choice!)*.

So what we see in the "pure set situation" is a near-complete collapse of logical notions: elementary equivalence/embedding/substructure mean almost the bare minimum of what they have to mean. The situation is far more interesting with even a little bit of structure involved, and this situation should really be thought of as pathological.